# Invite tester to use old versions with Crashlitycs Beta

Tags: android, crashlytics-beta

I want to invite a new tester to have access to all the existing builds from a project. Is it possible to do it without sending the invites one by one for each build?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no other / faster way to do it without sending the invites one by one for each build.